# TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT interfere input to other apps ~Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make Facebook Messanger Chat head like app that can show chat head from service. I read bunch of examples they all use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`. But the problem is it blocks input to all other apps so user won't be able to move screen, open app etc. Then I try to use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`, it shows the chat head and I can navigate through the screen freely, but now the chat head won't receive any input such as `onClick`.

So my question is, how to make chat head so that it won't block input to other app, and it still can receive input such as `onClick` or `onTouch`.

Heres how I create the view inside service's onCreate:

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.chat_popup, null);
```

Heres how I show the view from service:

```
private void showBubble() {
    try {
        mWindowManager.removeView(view);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mWindowManager.addView(view, params);
        trashView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isViewAdded = true;
    }
}
```

And heres my chat head layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profile_imageview"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="55dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_imageview"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/thumbnail" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/trash_button"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparentBlack"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know there's solution, but right now I'm stuck and I've been looking for solution with no luck.

Anyone can help?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for SIZE of WindowManager

```
int HW = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (pt number as dp), this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                HW,//width
                HW,//height
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

you current code set to MATCH_PARENT so it will block everything under that Window. also you have to define ViewGroup and then access its elements and then perform onClickListener. I have complete tutorial about it check [this tutorial](https://geeks3mpire.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/tutorial-creating-floating-app-floating_26.html)

```
viewgroup = (ViewGroup)vG.findViewById(R.id.widget);
relativeview = (RelativeLayout)vG.findViewById(R.id.whole_widget_view);
btn = (Button)vG.findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(...)
```

Comment: Yeah, the MATCH_PARENT seems to be the problem. Thanks, now it works.